# Having trouble opening Excel file with a For loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, path

I am having trouble opening Excel files using for loop. I have four Excel documents named Main, file 1, file 2 and file 3.

In the Main file, sheet "LOCATIONS", I have there paths in the cells: c:\file 1\file 1.xlsx in E3, c:\file 2\file 2.xlsx  in E4 and c:\file 2\file 3.xlsx in E5.

When I run the macro it only opens and closes the first one and then says "sorry could not find file2"

What am I missing?!

```
Sub TheOpener()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim CSW As String
Dim CSM As String
Dim H As Variant
Dim j As Integer

CSM = "C:\Main.xlsm"

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(CSM)

For j = 3 To 5

H = "E" & j

CSW = Chr$(34) & wb1.Worksheets("LOCATIONS").Range(H) & Chr$(34)

MsgBox CSW

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(CSW)

MsgBox "Open"

wb2.Close savechanges:=True

MsgBox "Closed"

Next j

End Sub
```

PS: This is my first post so I hope all is in order.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running the loop from 4 to 5 and confirm it still works on first file? You could also use Scripts FileSystemObject to check first that the file exists

Comment: You don't need to include the `Chr$(34)` in your path string.  Remove those, and provided the folders and files exist, you should be good to go